# Python: "AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute" argparse

Tags: python

My code looks like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Input path/to/file.csv', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-oh', '--output-html', help='Output path/to/confusion_matrix.html', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-oc', '--output-csv', help='Output path/to/confusion_matrix.csv', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

....

y_true = pd.Series(true_data, name="Actual")
y_pred = pd.Series(pred_data, name="Predicted")
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_true, y_pred)
df_confusion.to_html(args.output-html)
df_confusion.to_csv(args.output-csv)
```

When i try to run it, it gives me this error:

```
df_confusion.to_html(args.output-html)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'output'
```

However, if i change from

```
df_confusion.to_html(args.output-html)
```

To

```
df_confusion.to_html(args.output)
```

It works as it should. Can anyone explain why it doesn't work, and how can i make it work with args.output-html?

Comment: python sees `args.output-html` as "args.output minus html" and tries to do the subtraction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default (ie if you don't provide `dest` kwarg to `add_argument`) it changes `-` to `_` when creating the attribute since Python attributes can't contain the character `-` (as a matter of fact they can, but then they are only accessible by using `getattr`).

It means that you should change `args.output-html` to `args.output_html`, and `args.output-csv` to `args.output_csv`.